# WooCommerce add images to category loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get my Category images into my WooCommerce loop below but the array that's created from my code below doesn't seem to collect the image URL.

**PHP**

```
<?php $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'exclude' => '17,77')); ?>

    <?php foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) : ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $catTerm->slug; ?>"><?php echo $catTerm->name; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Would someone be kind enough to assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php $catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'exclude' => '17,77')); ?>

    <?php foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) : 
           $wthumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catTerm->term_id,'thumbnail_id', true );
           $wimage = wp_get_attachment_url( $wthumbnail_id );
    ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $catTerm->slug; ?>"><?php if($wimage!=""):?><img src="<?php echo $wimage?>"><?php endif;?><?php echo $catTerm->name; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Hope its works..

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to put the UL tag out of the foreach to no repeat the UL for each category.